# Blogger layout problem

Tags: html, css, xhtml, layout

This is my blog: http://laschavasdeflickr.blogspot.com

As you can see there is a grey line (#bbbbbb) there that its not on the edge, I am going crazy trying to fix it since I change the width of the post column. If someone can point me what I am doing wrong I will appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

<head>
  <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
  <title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
  <b:skin><![CDATA[/*
-----------------------------------------------
Blogger Template Style
Name:     Rounders 3
Designer: Douglas Bowman
URL:      www.stopdesign.com
Date:     27 Feb 2004
Updated by: Blogger Team
----------------------------------------------- */

/* Variable definitions
  ====================
   <Variable name="mainBgColor" description="Main Background Color"
             type="color" default="#eec" value="#eeeecc">
   <Variable name="mainTextColor" description="Text Color" type="color"
             default="#333" value="#333333">
   <Variable name="postTitleColor" description="Post Title Color" type="color"
             default="#333" value="#333333">
   <Variable name="dateHeaderColor" description="Date Header Color"
             type="color" default="#586" value="#558866">
   <Variable name="borderColor" description="Post Border Color" type="color"
             default="#bbb" value="#bbbbbb">


   <Variable name="mainLinkColor" description="Link Color" type="color"
             default="#456" value="#445566">
   <Variable name="mainVisitedLinkColor" description="Visited Link Color"
             type="color" default="#234" value="#223344">

   <Variable name="titleBgColor" description="Page Header Background Color"
             type="color" default="#357" value="#223344">
   <Variable name="titleTextColor" description="Blog Title Color"
             type="color" default="#fff" value="#ffffff">

   <Variable name="topSidebarHeaderColor"
             description="Top Sidebar Title Color"
             type="color" default="#fff" value="#ffffff">
   <Variable name="topSidebarBgColor"
             description="Top Sidebar Background Color"
             type="color" default="#586" value="#558866">
   <Variable name="topSidebarTextColor" description="Top Sidebar Text Color"
             type="color" default="#fff" value="#ffffff">
   <Variable name="topSidebarLinkColor" description="Top Sidebar Link Color"
             type="color" default="#fff" value="#ffffff">
   <Variable name="topSidebarVisitedLinkColor"
             description="Top Sidebar Visited Link Color"
             type="color" default="#fff" value="#ffffff">
   <Variable name="bottomSidebarHeaderColor"
             description="Bottom Sidebar Title Color"
             type="color" default="#abc" value="#aabbcc">

   <Variable name="bottomSidebarLinkColor"
             description="Bottom Sidebar Link Color"
             type="color" default="#99ddbb" value="#99ddbb">
   <Variable name="bottomSidebarVisitedLinkColor"
             description="Bottom Sidebar Visited Link Color"
             type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#ffffff">
   <Variable name="bodyFont" description="Text Font" type="font"
             default="normal normal 100% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif" value="normal normal 100% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="pageTitleFont" description="Blog Title Font" type="font"
             default="normal bold 200% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif" value="normal bold 200% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="descriptionFont" description="Blog Description Font" type="font"
             default="normal normal 100% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif" value="normal normal 100% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="headerFont" description="Sidebar Title Font" type="font"
             default="normal bold 100% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif" value="normal bold 100% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif">
   <Variable name="postTitleFont" description="Post Title Font" type="font"
             default="normal bold 135% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif" value="normal bold 135% 'Trebuchet MS',Verdana,Arial,Sans-serif">
*/

body {
  background:#123;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font: x-small Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
  color:$mainTextColor;
  font-size/* */:/**/small;
  font-size: /**/small;
  }


/* Page Structure
----------------------------------------------- */
/* The images which help create rounded corners depend on the 
   following widths and measurements. If you want to change 
   these measurements, the images will also need to change.
   */
#outer-wrapper {
  width:740px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:left;
  font: $bodyFont;
  }
#main-wrap1 {
  width:525px;
  float:left;
  background:$mainBgColor url("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2297/2045724843_5d984f0011_o.gif") no-repeat left bottom;
  margin:15px 0 0;
  padding:0 0 20px;
  color:$mainTextColor;
  font-size:97%;
  line-height:1.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word; /* fix for long text breaking sidebar float in IE */
  overflow: hidden;     /* fix for long non-text content breaking IE sidebar float */
  }
#main-wrap2 {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  background:url("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2357/2046504320_15aec77d32_o.gif") no-repeat left top;
  padding:10px 0 0;
  }
#main {
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/rails_main.gif") repeat-y;
  padding:0;
  }
#sidebar-wrap {
  width:200px;
  float:right;
  margin:15px 0 0;
  font-size:97%;
  line-height:1.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word; /* fix for long text breaking sidebar float in IE */
  overflow: hidden;     /* fix for long non-text content breaking IE sidebar float */
  }

.main .widget { 
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 525px;
  padding: 0 13px;
}

.main .Blog {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 525px;
}

/* Links
----------------------------------------------- */
a:link {
  color: $mainLinkColor;
  }
a:visited {
  color: $mainVisitedLinkColor;
  }
a:hover {
  color: $mainVisitedLinkColor;
  }
a img {
  border-width:0;
  }


/* Blog Header
----------------------------------------------- */
#header-wrapper {
  background:$titleBgColor url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/corners_cap_top.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin:22px 0 0 0;
  padding:8px 0 0 0;
  color:$titleTextColor;
  }
#header {
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/corners_cap_bot.gif") no-repeat left bottom;
  padding:0 15px 8px;
  }
#header h1 {
  margin:0;
  padding:10px 30px 5px;
  line-height:1.2em;
  font: $pageTitleFont;
  }
#header a,
#header a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: $titleTextColor;
  }
#header .description {
  margin:0;
  padding:5px 30px 10px;
  line-height:1.5em;
  font: $descriptionFont;
}


/* Posts
----------------------------------------------- */
h2.date-header {
  margin:0 28px 0 20px;
  font-size:85%;
  line-height:2em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:.2em;
  color:$dateHeaderColor;
  }
.post {
  margin:.3em 0 25px;
  padding:0 0;
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:1px 0;
  }
.post h3 {
  margin:0;
  line-height:1.5em;
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/icon_arrow.gif") no-repeat 10px .5em;
  display:block;
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:0px 1px 1px;
  padding:2px 14px 2px 29px;
  color: $postTitleColor;
  font: $postTitleFont;
  }
.post h3 a, .post h3 a:visited {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: $postTitleColor;
  }
a.title-link:hover {
  background-color: $borderColor;
  color: $mainTextColor;
  }
.post-body {
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:0 0px 0px;
  border-bottom-color:$mainBgColor;
  padding:10px 14px 1px 5px;
  }
html>body .post-body {
  border-bottom-width:0;
  }

.post p {
  margin:0 0 .75em;
  }
.post-footer {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin:0;
  padding:2px 14px 2px 29px;
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:1px;
  font-size:100%;
  line-height:1.5em;
  color: #666666;
}
.post-footer p { 
  margin: 0;
}
html>body .post-footer {
  border-bottom-color:transparent;
  }

.uncustomized-post-template .post-footer {
  text-align: right;
}

.uncustomized-post-template .post-author,
.uncustomized-post-template .post-timestamp {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.post-footer a { 
  color: #456;
 }
.post-footer a:hover { 
  color: #234;
 }
a.comment-link {
  /* IE5.0/Win doesn't apply padding to inline elements,
     so we hide these two declarations from it */
  background/* */:/**/url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders/icon_comment.gif") no-repeat 0 45%;
  padding-left:14px;
  }
html>body a.comment-link {
  /* Respecified, for IE5/Mac's benefit */
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/icon_comment.gif") no-repeat 0 45%;
  padding-left:14px;
  }
.post img {
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
  padding:4px;
  border:1px solid $borderColor;
  }
blockquote {
  margin:.75em 0;
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:1px 0;
  padding:5px 15px;
  color: $dateHeaderColor;
  }
.post blockquote p {
  margin:.5em 0;
  }

#blog-pager-newer-link {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 13px;
 }

#blog-pager-older-link {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 13px;
 }

#blog-pager {   
  text-align: center; 
 }

.feed-links { 
  clear: both;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-left: 13px;
}

/* Comments
----------------------------------------------- */
#comments {
  margin:-25px 13px 0;
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:0 1px 1px;
  padding:20px 0 15px 0;
  }
#comments h4 {
  margin:0 0 10px;
  padding:0 14px 2px 29px;
  border-bottom:1px dotted $borderColor;
  font-size:120%;
  line-height:1.4em;
  color:$postTitleColor;
  }
#comments-block {
  margin:0 15px 0 9px;
  }
.comment-author {
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/icon_comment.gif") no-repeat 2px .3em;
  margin:.5em 0;
  padding:0 0 0 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
.comment-body {
  margin:0 0 1.25em;
  padding:0 0 0 20px;
  }
.comment-body p {
  margin:0 0 .5em;
  }
.comment-footer {
  margin:0 0 .5em;
  padding:0 0 .75em 20px;
  }
.comment-footer a:link {
  color: #333;
  }
.deleted-comment {
  font-style:italic;
  color:gray;
  }


/* Profile
----------------------------------------------- */
.profile-img { 
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border: 4px solid $topSidebarTextColor;
}

.profile-datablock {
  margin:0 15px .5em 0;
  padding-top:8px;
}

.profile-link { 
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/icon_profile.gif") no-repeat 0 .1em;
  padding-left:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.profile-textblock {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar .clear, .main .widget .clear { 
  clear: both;
}

#sidebartop-wrap {
  background:$topSidebarBgColor url("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2329/2046538634_af629f2518_o.gif") no-repeat left bottom;
  margin:0px 0px 15px;
  padding:0px 0px 10px;
  color:$topSidebarTextColor;
  }

#sidebartop-wrap2 { 
 background:url("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2050/2045737079_76addfe5f6_o.gif") no-repeat left top;
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  margin:0;
  border-width:0;
 }

#sidebartop h2 {
  line-height:1.5em;
  color:$topSidebarHeaderColor;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted $topSidebarHeaderColor;
  font: $headerFont;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#sidebartop a { 
 color: $topSidebarLinkColor;
}

#sidebartop a:hover { 
 color: $topSidebarVisitedLinkColor;
}
#sidebartop a:visited { 
 color: $topSidebarVisitedLinkColor;
}

#sidebar a { 
  color: $bottomSidebarLinkColor;
}
#sidebar a:hover,
#sidebar a:visited { 
  color: $bottomSidebarVisitedLinkColor;
}

/* Sidebar Boxes
----------------------------------------------- */

.sidebar .widget { 
  margin:.5em 3px 1.25em;
  padding:0 0px;
 }

.widget-content { 
  margin-top: 0.5em;
 }

#sidebarbottom-wrap1 {
  background:$titleBgColor url("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2331/2046546608_f6d083f99a_o.gif") no-repeat left top;
  margin:0 0 15px;
  padding:10px 0 0;
  color: $titleTextColor;
}

#sidebarbottom-wrap2 {
  background:url("http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2063/2050854447_fedd0c67f1_o.gif") no-repeat left bottom;
  padding:0px 13px 8px;
}

.sidebar h2 {
  margin:0 0 .5em 0;
  padding:0 0 .2em;
  line-height:1.5em;
  font:$headerFont;
}

.sidebar ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 0 1.25em;
  padding:0 0px;
}

.sidebar ul li {
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/icon_arrow_sm.gif") no-repeat 2px .25em;
  margin:0;
  padding:0 0 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom:3px;
  border-bottom:1px dotted $borderColor;
  line-height:1.4em;
  }
.sidebar p {
  margin:0 0 .6em;
  }

#sidebar h2 { 
  color: $bottomSidebarHeaderColor;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted $bottomSidebarHeaderColor;
 }

/* Footer
----------------------------------------------- */
#footer-wrap1 {
  clear:both;
  margin:0;
  padding:15px 0 0;
  }
#footer-wrap2 {
  background:$titleBgColor url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/corners_cap_top.gif") no-repeat left top;
  padding:8px 0 0;
  color:$titleTextColor;
  }
#footer {
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/corners_cap_bot.gif") no-repeat left bottom;
  padding:0px 15px 8px;
  }
#footer hr {display:none;}
#footer p {margin:10;}
#footer a {color:$titleTextColor;}

/** Page structure tweaks for layout editor wireframe */
body#layout #main-wrap1,
body#layout #sidebar-wrap,
body#layout #header-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
}

body#layout #header, body#layout #header-wrapper,
body#layout #outer-wrapper { 
  margin-left:0,
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body#layout #outer-wrapper { 
  width: 730px;
}

body#layout #footer-wrap1 { 
  padding-top: 0;
 }
]]></b:skin>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='outer-wrapper'>

  <div id='header-wrapper'>
    <b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='1'>
<b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='Las Chavas de Flickr (cabecera)' type='Header'/>
</b:section>
  </div>

  <div id='crosscol-wrapper' style='text-align:center'>
    <b:section class='crosscol' id='crosscol' showaddelement='no'/>
  </div>

  <div id='main-wrap1'><div id='main-wrap2'>
    <b:section class='main' id='main' showaddelement='no'>
<b:widget id='Blog1' locked='true' title='Entradas del blog' type='Blog'/>
</b:section>
  </div></div>

  <div id='sidebar-wrap'>

    <div id='sidebartop-wrap'><div id='sidebartop-wrap2'>
      <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebartop'>
<b:widget id='HTML1' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
</b:section>
    </div></div>

    <div id='sidebarbottom-wrap1'><div id='sidebarbottom-wrap2'>
      <b:section class='sidebar' id='sidebar' preferred='yes'>
<b:widget id='Feed2' locked='false' title='MexAutos.com' type='Feed'/>
<b:widget id='LinkList1' locked='false' title='Links' type='LinkList'/>
<b:widget id='HTML6' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
<b:widget id='Feed1' locked='false' title='FreeUsedCarsAds.com' type='Feed'/>
<b:widget id='HTML4' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
<b:widget id='Feed3' locked='false' title='The Cars of You Tube' type='Feed'/>
<b:widget id='HTML2' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
<b:widget id='Feed4' locked='false' title='Google Reader' type='Feed'/>
<b:widget id='HTML7' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
<b:widget id='AdSense1' locked='false' title='' type='AdSense'/>
<b:widget id='HTML5' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
</b:section>
    </div></div>

  </div>

  <div id='footer-wrap1'><div id='footer-wrap2'>
    <b:section class='footer' id='footer'>
<b:widget id='HTML3' locked='false' title='' type='HTML'/>
</b:section>
  </div></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you really want to remove both lines? That's what the selected answer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by this bit of CSS.

```
#main {
  background:url("http://www.blogblog.com/rounders3/rails_main.gif") repeat-y;
  padding:0;
}
```

Take a look at that image, and you'll see it's that image which is loading and is putting the gray line there. Change it to this to get rid of it.

```
#main {
  background: transparent;
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but you might need to specify something like

margin:.3em 0 25px 0 0;
  padding:0 0 0 0;

instead of:

.post {
  margin:.3em 0 25px;
  padding:0 0;
  border:1px dotted $borderColor;
  border-width:1px 0;
  }

Answer (score 1):

The background image of the main div (rounders3/rails_main.gif) is 485 pixels wide. If you change the width of the column you have to make a new image that has the new width.